# Checking for multiple existence conditions, JSONpath

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the JSON below:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            } 
        ]
}
```

How can I construct a JSON path to retrieve the `book` elements that have `category`, `price`, and `title` elements? I've tried `$.store.book[?(@.price && @.category && @.title)]` but that doesn't work (it seems that kind of predicate doesn't allow for multiple conditions). Any ideas? Here's a link to a handy tester: https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: The path actually works fine with the Java port of [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath). The `&&` and `||` operators are only available in the Java port; the online tester uses a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out a way to do this with inline filters. However, it is possible to do it with a filter object:

```
Filter f = filter(where("price").exists(true).and(where("category").exists(true).and(where("titles").exists(true));
```

When calling read: `JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[?]", f);`